# Google App Engine Bronze Level Support unusable?

Tags: google-app-engine

This seems to be the only place to get help without going to Silver support. But when you have a problem that does not belong here, are you really left with no recourse?

If yes, this would seem to make GAE unusable, or at least a dangerous gamble, for those that do not have $150 a month to spend on errors that is caused by Google themselves.

Comment: Question appears to be about Google App Engine support, not programming

Comment: Google refers support questions here. Catch 22?

Comment: At a guess, they refer support about GAE programming related issues here, which would be on-topic. This kind of question has never been on-topic for Stack Overflow, and never will be. At the least this kind of question will attract opinion and not fact.

Comment: Also to note : bronze support entitles you to billing support. Between that, technical support (that can be achieved here), and Google's Issue trackers to post Feature Requests and Defect Reports, you should have all the resources you need.

Comment: Thank you. Google's Issue tracker was the answer. You should add that as a real answer, instead of a comment. The link to there ( [https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3] )would be useful. No support page at Google that I could find (in relation to App Engine Support) link to or even mention the issue tracker.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "problems that are caused by Google themselves"??? If you experience a bug on the platform, you post it to the issue tracker. Otherwise, if you have a bug with your own code, you post it to stack overflow. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Is it not enough that the platform's engineers are reading and responding to the issue tracker threads (when it's a valid platform issue and not a bug in your own code)? Do you somehow want free support which is over and above that?

Comment: Bronze level is not free, it's billed by usage. I expect to fix bugs in my own code. I also expect some way to report bugs not in my own code. It was the lack of that possibility that led to my complaint. If they had put a link to the issue tracker where they linked to stackoverflow, my complaint would never have happened. I do not think that was too much to ask, but I apologize for annoying you by posting here in desperation.

Comment: Feel free to delete my question. Or tell me to do it. I just think the very lacking linking to other places than here from GAE could be compensated by having an answer here pointing to the issues page at Google. Of course my ranting question might not be he best candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have specific Feature Requests to make or Defect Reports (for the whole platform, the way I understood it, it will be closed if it is something just related to your own problem).

[Here is the link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3])

Comment: I suspect this is a general defect. Might need something special to trigger, but I don't think they want this to happen to too many users. I'll just have to wait and see if it stops, they say they don't reply to these individually.